# Google reverse geocoding JSON: what is the property to match city name worldwide?

Tags: php, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Reverse Geocoding to parse coordinates all around the world.
I'm experiencing difficulty in matching the right "administrative area level" for every country from the JSON response.

Here is an example of response: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.709073,%20-74.007506&language=en-EN

According to [Address Types and Address Component Types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) I could search for property among these:

- political
- administrative_area_level_1
- administrative_area_level_2
- administrative_area_level_3
- administrative_area_level_4
- administrative_area_level_5
- colloquial_area
- locality
- ward
- sublocality
- neighborhood

Here is my attempt with a PHP function:

```
public static function getCity($json) {
    $types = array('administrative_area_level_1', 'administrative_area_level_2', 'administrative_area_level_3', 'locality', 'country');

    foreach ($json["results"] as $result) {
        foreach ($types as $t) {

            if ($city = self::Find_Long_Name_Given_Type($t, $result['address_components'])) {
                return $city;
            }
        } 
    }
}

private static function Find_Long_Name_Given_Type($type, $array, $short_name = false) {
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (in_array($type, $value["types"])) {
            if ($short_name) {
                return $value["short_name"];
            }
            return $value["long_name"];
        }
    }
}
```

(As you can see I search for country if none of other properties is given)

I noticed that some places have at least one of all the properties in the above list. So, what should be the property that worth it for all cities in the world?
How should I parse every pair of coordinates to get the right (english) name of the city?

For example I have noticed that a certain field contains the city name for European cities but is not the same field for American cities. So, how can I get the correct property for every country in the world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no unique property (address component) for the city name worldwide. In different countries and different areas of the same country you can have a city name in different address components. I believe the address component choice depends on the internal data modelling used by Google in different countries.

Have a look at the following sample page:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

You can see the following explanation on this page

> You may need to adjust it to align with postal addresses of each country. This example displays the **locality** address component from the database. This often represents the city. However, in UK and Sweden the correct component is **postal_town**, while the correct component in Japan is different across prefectures. Brooklyn and other parts of New York City do not use the city as part of the address. They use **sublocality_level_1** instead.

So, at least you can play with locality, postal_town and sublocality_level_1 mentioned there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, anyway your solution doesn't work for some European country. So, there is no solution :(